# Atribuir valor a uma variével Boolean de acordo com Radio Button selecionado

Tags: postgresql, variáveis, delphi-7, radiobutton

Estou tentando implementar minha aplicação, onde a tabela `empresa` ganhou uma nova coluna chamada `status`, que seria preenchida de acordo com o `Radio Button` isso iria servir para que na hora de gerar os relatórios de clientes vinculados, o mesmo só me trouxesse os clientes com **Status = Ativo**, sou iniciante em Delphi, por esse motivo não estou conseguindo, de acordo com o `Radio Button` preencher essa coluna. Já consegui no **form** de cadastro de empresas adicionar os `Radio Buttons` ficando assim a tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A parte onde salva essas informações no banco hoje esta dessa forma:

```
begin
    sdsEmpresaCadastro.Close;
    sdsEmpresaCadastro.CommandText := 'select * from Empresa where Nome = '''+cdsEmpresaNOME.AsString + '''';
    sdsEmpresaCadastro.Open;

    if not sdsEmpresaCadastro.IsEmpty then
       raise  Exception.Create('Empresa já incluída');
    cdsEmpresaCODIGO.AsInteger := dmDatabase.NextID('EMPRESA');

    dmDatabase.SQLConnection.Execute('INSERT INTO Empresa (CODIGO, NOME, VALORIMPRESSAO, '+
         'VALORDIGITALIZACAO, VALORIMPRESSAOEXCEDENTE, CONTATO, NOMEREDUZIDO, CNPJ, ENDERECO, BAIRRO, CEP, '+
         'CIDADE, TEFONE, UF, INSCRICAOESTADUAL, CONTATONF, EMAIL, EMAILNF, OBSERVACAO, '+
         'FRANQUIADIGITALIZACAO, VALORDIGITALIZACAOEXCEDENTE, STATUS) VALUES ('+
         cdsEmpresaCODIGO.AsString+','''+cdsEmpresaNOME.AsString+''','+
         TrocaVirgPPto(cdsEmpresaVALORIMPRESSAO.AsString)+','+
         iif(cdsEmpresaVALORDIGITALIZACAO.AsString='','0', TrocaVirgPPto(cdsEmpresaVALORDIGITALIZACAO.AsString))+','+
         iif(cdsEmpresaVALORIMPRESSAOEXCEDENTE.AsString='','0', TrocaVirgPPto(cdsEmpresaVALORIMPRESSAOEXCEDENTE.AsString))+
         ','''+cdsEmpresaCONTATO.AsString+''','''+cdsEmpresaNOMEREDUZIDO.AsString+ ''','''+
         cdsEmpresaCNPJ.AsString +''','''+cdsEmpresaENDERECO.AsString+''','''+
         cdsEmpresaBAIRRO.AsString +''','''+cdsEmpresaCEP.AsString+ ''','''+
         cdsEmpresaCIDADE.AsString+''','''+cdsEmpresaTEFONE.AsString+''','''+
         cdsEmpresaUF.AsString+''','''+cdsEmpresaINSCRICAOESTADUAL.AsString+ ''','''+
         cdsEmpresaCONTATONF.AsString+ ''','''+ cdsEmpresaEMAIL.AsString + ''','''+
         cdsEmpresaOBSERVACAO.AsString + ''','''+ cdsEmpresaEMAILNF.AsString+''','+
         iif(cdsEmpresaFRANQUIADIGITALIZACAO.AsString='','0', cdsEmpresaFRANQUIADIGITALIZACAO.AsString)+','+
         iif(cdsEmpresaVALORDIGITALIZACAOEXCEDENTE.AsString='','0', TrocaVirgPPto(cdsEmpresaVALORDIGITALIZACAOEXCEDENTE.AsString))+')', nil);
  end
```

Minha dúvida então é: Como verificar qual dos `Radio Buttons` está selecionado, para assim atribuir ao banco se **Status = true** ou **false**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode verificar a propriedade `Checked` do `RadioButton`. Seria algo assim:

```
if RadioButton1.Checked then
  ShowMessage('Ativo!')
else
  ShowMessage('Inativo!');
```

No seu caso, ao carregar os dados do cliente no `ClientDataSet` você deverá verificar a coluna `Status` e marcar o `RadioButton` correspondente, da mesma forma ao aplicar as alterações realizadas você deverá verificar qual `RadioButton` foi selecionado e montar adequadamente a instrução SQL.

Te indico a usar o componente `DBRadioGroup`você vai ter menos trabalho. Ele é parecido como os componentes dataware que já está usando (DBEdits). Você precisa definir as propriedades `DataSource` e `DataField` como fez nos DBEdits, depois disso você adiciona os RadioButtons na propriedade `Itemns`, nela você informa um item abaixo do outro como em uma lista. Depois você define a propriedade `Values` com os valores que serão gravados no campo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]